# Javascript: Changing the colour of dynamic api data?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner at HTML/Javascript and I need some help to make my first price ticker.
So far I've managed to obtain and display the data from Coinmarketcap's API but I want to add some functionality.

How can I create a function that will change the colour of the price change value based on whether it is positive or negative 
(green for positive and red for negative)?

```js
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1697/')
.then(res => res.json())
.then((res) => {
  const data = res.data;
  getElement('usdprice').innerHTML = "$" + data.quotes.USD.price;
  getElement('change').innerHTML = data.quotes.USD.percent_change_24h + "%";
 
});
```

```css
#table{
  border-spacing: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

#usdprice{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#change{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td id="usdprice" ></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="change" ></td>
</table>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're missing `</tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1697/')
.then(res => res.json())
.then((res) => {
  const data = res.data;
  getElement('usdprice').innerHTML = "$" + data.quotes.USD.price;
  getElement('change').innerHTML = data.quotes.USD.percent_change_24h + "%";
  getElement('change').classList.remove('plus','minus')      
  getElement('change').classList.add( data.quotes.USD.percent_change_24h > 0 ? 'plus' : 'minus');
 
});
```

```css
#table{
   border-spacing: 2em;
   text-align: center;
 }

 #usdprice{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

#change{
  //color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.plus {
  color: green;
}

.minus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td id="usdprice" ></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="change" ></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to add an extra class name to the table cell based on the price.

```
const data = res.data;
getElement('usdprice').innerHTML = "$" + data.quotes.USD.price;
getElement('change').innerHTML = data.quotes.USD.percent_change_24h + "%";

if(data.quotes.USD.price < 0)
    getElement('usdprice').className = "negative"; // If price is negative add the 'negative' class
```

And in your CSS

```
#usdprice {
    color: green;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#usdprice.negative {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure if you want change the color of `#usdprice` cell or `#change` cell, but I think the following code will help you:

```
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1697/')
.then(res => res.json())
.then((res) => {
  const data = res.data;
  document.getElementById('usdprice').innerHTML = "$" + data.quotes.USD.price;
  document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = data.quotes.USD.percent_change_24h + "%";

  if(data.quotes.USD.price >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('usdprice').style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('usdprice').style.color = 'red';
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Pleasure to help